# Installing SSL certificate on remote website hosted on IIS 7

Tags: windows, ssl, iis-7, remote-access

I want to generate a CSR and install an SSL certificate for my website. I just found out that my webmaster hosted it on IIS 7 so it's different from what I'm used to.

I've set up IIS 10 and want to add my website to my server so that I can bind the SSL certificate to it. The website has some content on it so I'm afraid that if I add the website, I'd end up losing the content since I don't have a copy of the files on my computer.

Is it possible for me to add the website so that I can generate the CSR and install the SSL certificate remotely? Or is there something I'd have to ask the webmaster to do for me before I can do it myself?

Comment: "I just found out that my webmaster hosted it on IIS 7" is a red flag. If you don't have full control of that remote machine (such as remote desktop access), then only your webmaster can answer your question, while no others can.

Comment: I guess that means I'll have to ask him to make the server remotely accessible. Thanks